# Count and summarise ID and the Date of Purchase while creating a third column that reflects the amount of Purchased per one day and Customer

Tags: r

Good afternoon dear Community,

I am quite new in the R language so forgive me if I am not to precise or specific with my description of the problem yet.

I have a data frame which contains two columns. First one being the ID and second one being the Date of purchase. However, some ID's appear more often during one Date and I would like to summarise the ID and Date, while the third column (amount of Purchases) reflects the quantity of purchases.
[ID and Purchase Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnxRW.png)

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: can you provide some samples of input and expected result so that other can help you more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an R package called dplyr that makes this kind of aggregation very easy. In your case you could summarise the data using a few lines of code.

```
library(dplyr)
results <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  summarise(numPurchases = n(),
            totalPurchases = sum(Quantity))
```

df would be your input data. Your results will have the ID and Date columns, as well as a new column that counts the number of sales per ID per Date (numPurchases) and a new column that shows the total quantity of purchases per ID per date (totalPurchases). Hope that helps.